# Name Error: name 'add' is not defined

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, random, nameerror

it my first time using Stack Overflow so please excuse any mistakes i have made. Im creating a program and i want ask mathematical questions for the user. But my program will generate two random numbers, and a random arithmetic operator will occur. They are plus, minus and times. So i put them into an array and this is the code.

Code:

[image]

The Error i gained:

[image]

It said the Error is in Line 10.

Ive tried doing this 'What is'+str(Ran) +,+str(op) +,+str(dom) +'?')
However i gained an invalid syntax on the comma.

Ive tried searching for this particular program, but all of them seem to have something called classes and def in. If it is possible, can i please not use the def and class in my program because i am new to python and i still need to learn what they are.

I am using Python 3.4.2, on a Windows 8 operating system if you wanted to know.
Thanks for reading, i am looking forward to have any assistance in my problem.

Comment: Could you edit the question to include your code please?

Comment: Please post the code and the error traceback here!

Comment: How do i do that? Sorry its my first time using this website

Comment: @user3634055 Click the "edit" link under the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+ +` is invalid syntax. You should be doing `str(something) + ' ' + string(something_else)` if you want to add two strings with a space in between. You also need quotes around `add`, `minus` and `times` in the list in order to make them strings.

Comment: Thank you for your help :D I got it working however i am now facing another problem. I shall post another question though

Comment: No problem. If this answer helped you, it would be great if you could accept it.

Comment: Done :D Sorry i didn't know what that was xD